# Fetch another site's localstorage data

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have two different site's data stored in localstorage, let's say xyz.com and abc.com. The thing is i can only access the data in which site I'm currently on. How can I access localstorage of abc.com if I'm on xyz.com?

Comment: Fortunately, you can't.

Comment: Yeah, that'd be convenient, wouldn't it? :)
This is by design and shouldn't be possible. Ever.

Comment: It's impossible because of security problems...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have already pointed out in the comments this is not possible.

If you read the documentation for [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) (which consists of both localStorage and sessionStorage) you will see this.

> A different Storage object is used for the sessionStorage and localStorage for each origin — they function and are controlled separately.

An origin in this context is defined as this.

> Web content's origin is defined by the scheme (protocol), hostname (domain), and port of the URL used to access it. Two objects have the same origin only when the scheme, hostname, and port all match.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin

Since you in your example have two different hostnames, they are separate origins and therefore can't access each others localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you CAN, by using the below code in the domain1.html:

```
<form action="domain2.html"> 
.......code
....... localStorage.setItem("key", value);
.......code
</form>
```

The action of this form is applied on domain2.html.

If you want to see an example, watch this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOe0ysNsNCo

---

The only drawback of this technic is that the data is stored only and only in the local storage of the second domain (domain2.html) and not in the first domain (domain1.html) so the data is not cross domain.

However there is a trick to overcome this limitation:

1. store the data in the local storage of the first domain domain1.html
2. Pass the data from domain1.html to domain2.html after an action it can be "button click" or "window onload".

Comment: Can you also read data from other domain in local storage?

Comment: This only allows for sending data to another page on the same domain, which is exactly what localStorage/sessionStorage is supposed to do since it is within the same origin. It has nothing to do with the `form` element, the "action" is not performed on the target page, it is set via a script on the first page and read with a script on ther other one.